# Implementing dynamic UIPickerView list with SwiftForms

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am using [SwiftForms](https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms) to create a UIPickerView for my form. The way this is done in the SwiftForms example is as follows:

```
    row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: "thingsTag", rowType: .Picker, title: "Things")
    row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = [1, 2, 3]
    row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.TitleFormatterClosure] = { value in
        switch( value ) {
        case 1:
            return "Thing 1"
        case 2:
            return "Thing 2"
        case 3:
            return "Thing 3"
        default:
            return nil
        }
        } as TitleFormatterClosure
    section1.addRow(row)
```

Obviously this route requires you to have a predetermined array of "things" to choose from. However, I have a dynamic array that is different for every user, depending on previous selections they have made in the app. (Sometimes the picker will have 3 choices, sometimes it will have 5, 9 etc.)

How can I get the `row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.TitleFormatterClosure` portion to work correctly without a switch statement? I know a for loop would be better suited for this but I could not figure out how to get it to work without throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your titles for the picker view in a array, why not just use subscript syntax to get the title from the array, using the value var?

Let's assume you have the following array defined, and initialized with the following values.

```
let possibleOptions = ["Doctor", "Teacher", "Engineer", "Politician"]
```

(Note that this is let in my example, as nothing should be modifying it. If your picker view adds/removes values based on entered input your array will have to be a var.)

Then, in the closure, assuming that your array is in the order that you want it to display in, then you can just return the following in the closure:

```
return possibleOptions[value]
```

However, due note that if you try and subscript a value from the array that *doesn't* exist, then your program will crash. Assuming your implementation of everything is correct, this shouldn't happen however it wouldn't hurt to check for it when returning a title for the picker view.

The final code would look something like this:

```
row = FormRowDescriptor(tag: "thingsTag", rowType: .Picker, title: "Things")
row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] = [1, 2, 3]
row.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.TitleFormatterClosure] = { value in
    return possibleOptions[value]
    } as TitleFormatterClosure
section1.addRow(row)
```

Comment: With this I am receiving the error "Cannot assign a value of type 'TitleFormatterClosure' to a value of type 'Any?'"